# Insert text above inserted Outlook table

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have an Outlook macro which inserts a table in an Outlook meeting.

However I want to add a text before the table which I am unable to do.

Here is my code for macro

```vb
Sub InsertText()

    Const sText As String = "Enter this text at the cursor"
    
   ' On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    If TypeName(ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
      
        If ActiveInspector.IsWordMail And ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
             
            With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.ActiveDocument
              
                .Tables.Add Range:=.Range, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:= _
                  2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
                  wdAutoFitFixed

                With .Tables(1)
                    If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
                         .Style = "Table Grid"
                    End If
                    .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
                    .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
                    .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
                    .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
                    .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
                    .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
                    .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Meeting purpose"
                    .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "The purpose of this meeting to discuss business future"
                    .Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Meeting Participants"
                    .Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Participant task for the meeting"
                End With
            End With
        
        End If
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Some Error"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use the following code:

```
Dim rng as Word.Range

With ActiveInspector.WordEditor
                Set rng = .Range(0, 0);
                rng.Text = "New Text"

                .Tables.Add Range:=.Range, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:= _
                2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
                wdAutoFitFixed
                With .Tables(1)
                    If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
                     .Style = "Table Grid"
                    End If
                    .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
                    .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
                    .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
                    .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
                    .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
                    .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
                    .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Meeting purpose"
                    .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "The purpose of this meeting to discuss business future"
                    .Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Meeting Participants"
                    .Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Participant task for the meeting"
                 End With
        End With
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for your response, but the text doesn't appear above the table. Could you please review the code.

Comment: You need to play with indexes.